# Javascript, getDay() returning wrong number

Tags: javascript, date

To start off, I know that the day of week in javascript starts at 0, Sunday = 0, Saturday = 6.

However, there is something simple that I am missing here, but the following code always returns what I want, but 1 less.

This should return 6, but returns 5.

```
var string = "2014-06-21";
var temp = new Date(string);
alert(temp.getDay());
```

Anybody have any ideas whats going wrong, and how it may be fixed? Thanks.

Comment: "2014-06-21" is a saturday.

Comment: The days start from 0

Comment: @kidwon Days of week start at 0 (as the OP already mentioned), but days of month start at 1

Answer (score 4):

If you create a date from a string be sure to specify the time:

```
var string = "2014-06-21 00:00:00";
var temp = new Date(string);
alert(temp.getDay());
```

You are probably getting the previous day because you are not specifying the time (in the date string). In this case, your current time zone will be used (mine is GMT-03h)

Another option is to create a date using the `Date` constructor which takes numbers as it's parameters:

```
new Date(year,month,day);
```

Or, in your case:

```
var temp = new Date(2014, 6, 21);
alert(temp.getDay());
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't specify a time in your string it will default to your current time zone.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse