# Javascript Date getDay() format issue

Tags: javascript, date

I'm having a issue is JS trying to get the day of the week of a specific date:

```
const searchDate = "2021-02-04";
const serchDateDayOfWeek = new Date( searchDate ).getDay();
console.log( serchDateDayOfWeek ) // => 3
```

I assumed that the result would be 4 (Thursday) but it is 3 (Wednesday).

What would be the correct way to get the day of week value without modifying the format of the seachDate?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Works as expected. Add one........

Comment: Very strange, I got the same thing, it should be 4. I ran it with momentjs and it returns 4.

Comment: Yes @CaioMar using momentjs returns 4. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update:

In MDN, Date constructors syntax includes

```
new Date()
new Date(value)
new Date(dateString)
new Date(year, monthIndex [, day [, hours [, minutes [, seconds [, milliseconds]]]]])
```

"2021-02-04" is a dateString which is [strongly discouraged](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date#parameters) by MDN( This reference is wildly distributed in Internet ^v^ )

> Parsing of date strings with the Date constructor (and Date.parse(), which works the same way) is strongly discouraged due to browser differences and inconsistencies.

> Support for RFC 2822 format strings is by convention only.
> Support for ISO 8601 formats differs in that date-only strings (e.g. "1970-01-01") are treated as UTC, not local.

**In brief, there are many international standards that create conflicts in dateString mode.** Different browsers may use different standards, that is "browser differences". So that's why I run your code in [mdn](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PqsiN.png), the output is 4 which is different from yours.

There is another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57600841/ambiguous-behavior-of-javascript-new-date-constructor-for-same-different-forma) facing the same situation as yours, and the output is smaller than the correct result by 1 as yours.

If you Google, you will find many people are trapped. I think this answer should be filed with other answers like:

- [Ambiguous behavior of javascript new Date() constructor for same different formatted string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57600841/ambiguous-behavior-of-javascript-new-date-constructor-for-same-different-forma)
- [Why does Date.parse give incorrect results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/why-does-date-parse-give-incorrect-results)
- [Date.getDay() is returning different values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41358853/date-getday-is-returning-different-values)
- [Javascript, getDay() returning wrong number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24250558/javascript-getday-returning-wrong-number)
- [getDay() return wrong day if day is with leading zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48696566/getday-return-wrong-day-if-day-is-with-leading-zero)
- [Date.getDay() returns wrong day of the week](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36494162/date-getday-returns-wrong-day-of-the-week)
- ...

So, I strongly recommend don't use dateString to construct Date. Just use `new Date(2021, 02, 04)`, you will get the correct answer.

Comment: I don't know why, but I'm getting 3 as output in the same MDN link.

Comment: Could you please add a screenshot? Or Provide your browser version, code editor version, compiler version and so on. Need more information.

Comment: Here is the screenshot -> [link](https://pasteboard.co/JMO3JAu.png)

Comment: That's interesting and there are others who have experienced similar problems. E.g.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36494162/date-getday-returns-wrong-day-of-the-week      Which country do you live in now, Mexico?

Comment: I'm from Argentina. I think that the format of searchDate is the problem. Because if the format be "2021-02-04T00:00:00" the output is 4. [link](https://pasteboard.co/JMOjw9C.png)

Answer (score 1):

To solve for this, you need to make an array containing names of the days in order.  And on the index end of the array, put `new Date().getDay()` inside the index of the array, and should return a result.

```
console.log([
     "Sunday",
     "Monday",
     "Tuesday",
     "Wendesday",
     "Thursday",
     "Friday",
     "Saturday"
][
    new Date().getDay()
])
```

The above will assign a named day based on the index number `new Date().getDay()` produces.

Comment: If the number makes the day less than 1, move the first index of the array to the last until it satisfies your arguement.